# Let bash treat error inside condition as error

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to write a robust bash script and I use `set -e` to make sure the script will stop running whenever something goes wrong.  It works great but there is still one hole: conditions.   If I write `if f; then .... fi` and function `f` fails on executing some command, the script will not be terminated.  Therefore I need to check return code of every command in `f`, as well as in all the subroutines `f` invoke, recursively.  This is annoying.

Is there something, e.g. some flag or option in bash, that makes it fail even inside a condition.  The only exception is `return` statement directly inside `f`.  If `f` calls `g` and `g` returns 1, then it is still considered as error, with the exception that `g` is also called as condition, i.e. `if g; then ... fi`, then `return` statement inside `g` is allowed.  So on so forth.

Comment: BashFAQ #105 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 -- is relevant here. Doesn't fully answer your question -- since the answer is "no, you can't do that" (since there's only a single return status used for both returning false and describing errors), but describes the corner cases and exceptions to `set -e` and ERR trap behavior in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Succinctly, No.

If you want the shell to exit on failure, don't test `f`; simply run it.  The code in the `then` clause should simply follow the invocation of `f` because you'll only ever get to execute it if `f` succeeded.

Old code:

```
set -e
if f; then echo "f succeeded"; fi
```

New code:

```
set -e
f
echo "f succeeded"
```

You'll only see "f succeeded" if it does succeed; if it fails, the `set -e` ensures the script exits.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking to do is slightly odd.  I can imagine two possibilities for why you're asking:

1. You want the script to exit if anything goes wrong inside the body of the function `f`, *even if the function itself still returns success*.
2. You want to distinguish between the function successfully computing what turns out to be a legitimate false value, and failing.

For case 1 - don't do that.  If anything goes wrong inside `f`, the function should absolutely return false (if not exit the whole script itself).  And if it returns false, you're good - see @JonathanLeffler's answer.

For case 2, you're effectively trying to make `$?` serve two duties.  It can be either an error indicator or a Boolean result; it can't be both.

If you want your script to exit if something goes wrong, you could just have the function itself call `exit` when that happens, so the caller doesn't have to worry about that case.

Alternatively, you could have the function `echo` its computed Boolean value instead of returning it, and reserve `$?` for success/failure.  Something like this, maybe:

```
f() {
   if that thing is true; then
     echo 1
   else
     echo 0
   fi
   if something went wrong; then
     return 1
   else
     return 0
   fi
}
result=$(f)   # we'll blow up and exit if f returns nonzero in `$?`
if (( result )); then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: I like your idea of using `echo` vs `return` to distinguish between error and false, I'll probably use it as the workaround in my code.  On the other hand, I want to make my point a little more clear.  My point is, if I want to write a robust shell script, I'll have to check the return code of every command that potentially goes wrong.  Then the logic is, if some command is not wrapped by condition, e.g. `if` or `&&`, etc., then I would expect it never returns non-zero; if it does, then it is something unexpected and the script should terminate.  Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to distinguish between `f` being *false* and `f` encountering an error.

Traditionally both falsehood and error conditions are signaled in the same way: by setting `$?` to a non-zero value.

*Some* commands do make such a distinction. For example, the `grep` command sets `$?` to `0` if the pattern was found, `1` if it wasn't, and `2` if there was an error (such as a missing file). So for the `grep` command, you could do something like:

```
grep ...
case $? in
    0) # ok
       ;;
    1) # pattern not found
       ;;
    *) # error
       ;;
esac
```

But that's specific to `grep`. There is no universal convention for distinguishing between a command yielding a "false" result and failing, and in many cases there is no such distinction to make.

To do what you want, you'll have to define just what constitutes an error, and then determine for each command you might execute how to detect an error condition.